# Best way to do html e-mail, sending via php?

Tags: php, html, email

I've never done html e-mail before, I've just set up php mail using http://www.postmarkapp.com

I was wondering how I would go about sending php mail as html?

Does anybody have any previews of a php page sending html e-mail I can look at to get the jist of how it works?

Currently I'm just putting text into a variable and sending it as a message, how is it done for html?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you still want to use Postmark to send emails?

In Postmark, you set the `TextBody` property to the text version of your message, and the `HtmlBody` property to the html version of it. It is good practice to always include both. Depending on whether your user's email client supports HTML or not, the appropriate message form is rendered. Read more on this [here](http://help.postmarkapp.com/discussions/questions/4-htmlbody-vs-textbody).

Edit: Added an example. I generally like splitting my string into separate lines so that I can indent it nicely like a real HTML file. Of course, if you used templates, that would make it so much better.

```
$htmlBody = "
<html>
    <body>
        Thank you for using our app!<br />
        - Super Awesome App Team
    </body>
</html>
";
```

Comment: I assume just using HtmlBody will make postmark send the contents as a html e-mail, I will give it a go, when actually doing the html for the e-mail, do I need to use <html>, <body>, etc etc? or do I just write the html?

Comment: Yes, you need to include the tags in the string. There's no HTML without tags. :) You can skip the <head> tag though.

Answer (score 1):

Put the html code inside the variable where you need as you are doing while creating web pages and set the mail header to text/html.

```
$headers.= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers.= "From: eaxfd@gmail.com \r\n";
$headers.= "Reply-To: eaxfd@gmail.com \r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

This is the best class I've found to send mail with PHP.  It allows HTML formatting with alternate plain text part, as well as attachments.   It also seems to filter out spam quite well when used for online forms.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to include html headers in your call to the `mail()` function:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```