# formatting email in php?

Tags: php, html, email

```
$to = "$email";
$subject = "Thank You";
$message = "<p>Thanks for applying</p>";
$from = "solomon@kornar.com";
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

when i send this email to myself, i still see the html tags, why is this thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to do html e-mail, sending via php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336155/best-way-to-do-html-e-mail-sending-via-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send the `Content-type` header as `text/html`.

For example, change the `$headers` line to

```
$headers = "From: $from";
$headers .= "\nContent-type: text/html";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your headers content type. Like:

```
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: I know that choosing a charset depends on the developer's needs and situation, but do you really think that suggesting `ISO-8859-1` as a sensible default is a good idea today? I'd really recommend using `UTF-8` instead.

Comment: @Delan Azabai - Thanks, i actually changed my answer while you were typing your comment.